# How to Intersect two Arrays?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, intersection

I'm working with VB.Net, and have two one-dimensional Arrays. Is there an Inbuilt function for finding the elements that are common to both of them? Or do I have to write one for myself?

Comment: similar question is at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/245557/algorithm-to-find-if-two-sets-intersect

But it does not answer my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you'll have to write one for yourself, because there is no built-in function in .NET 2.0.

Look at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/674075/vb-net-array-intersection) for ideas about how you could implement it yourself.

Answer (score 9):

If you can use the LINQ extension methods (VB9), then yes - you can use [`Enumerable.Intersect()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136.aspx):

```
dim a as String() = {"blah", "bleak", "blorg", "blue"}
dim b as String() = {"blaah", "bleak", "bleee", "blue"}

' c will contain the intersection, "bleak" and "blue" '
dim c as IEnumerable(Of String) = a.Intersect(b)
```

Comment: +1 for this, OP should be aware however that this is a VB9.0 solution, if he is using VB8.0 (Visual Studio 2005) this won't work for him.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm still working with VB8.0 with 2.0 .NET framework, so looks like I'm out of luck

Answer (score 1):

Just use LinqBridge for .net 2.0 http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/downloads/list and you should be able to use the intersect method.