# Finding common elements in two arrays of different size

Tags: c, algorithm

I have a problem to find common elements in two arrays and that's of different size.

Take , Array `A1` of size `n` and Array `A2` of size `m`, and `m != n`

So far, I've tried to iterate lists one by one and copy elements to another list. If the element already contains mark it, but I know it's not a good solution.

Comment: If language is not important: in c# is `list1.Intersect(list2)`

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/189504/finding-common-elements-in-two-arrays

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Sort the arrays. Then iterate through them with two pointers, always advancing the one pointing to the smaller value. When they point to equal values, you have a common value. This will be O(n log n+m log m) where n and m are the sizes of the two lists. It's just like a merge in [merge sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), but where you only produce output when the values being pointed to are equal.

```
def common_elements(a, b):
  a.sort()
  b.sort()
  i, j = 0, 0
  common = []
  while i < len(a) and j < len(b):
    if a[i] == b[j]:
      common.append(a[i])
      i += 1
      j += 1
    elif a[i] < b[j]:
      i += 1
    else:
      j += 1
  return common

print 'Common values:', ', '.join(map(str, common_elements([1, 2, 4, 8], [1, 4, 9])))
```

outputs

```
Common values: 1, 4
```

If the elements aren't comparable, throw the elements from one list into a hashmap and check the elements in the second list against the hashmap.

Comment: hm, What would the output be in case it was `[1,1,1,2,2,4]` and `[1,1,1,2,2,2,5]` ? If I read correct shouldn't you also check if it already exists in `common` ? unless you clean up the duplicates in `common_elements` later in your code.

Comment: @Muggen 1, 1, 1, 2, 2. If you want the output to be distinct values, add a `while i < len(a) and j < len(b) and a[i] == b[j]:` before incrementing `i` and `j`.

Comment: Nice. +1. What language is that btw ?

Comment: This is order (mlog m + nlog n) not m+n, since you are sorting both arrays.

Comment: Its not actually m log m + n log n, you only sort each array once not for each item. It is thus correct to say it is O(m + n) because the lower order terms are dropped.

Comment: sorting both arrays is mlogm and nlogn as well as m + n for your algorithm so it is O(mlogm + nlogn + m + n) so it is overall O(nlogn)

Comment: Could use a hash table for O(n + m) algorithm, but that would be O(n) memory

Answer (score 21):

If you want to make it efficient I would convert the smaller array into a hashset and then iterate the larger array and check whether the current element was contained in the hashset. The hash function is efficient compared to sorting arrays. Sorting arrays is expensive.

Here's my sample code

```
import java.util.*;
public class CountTest {     
    public static void main(String... args) {        
        Integer[] array1 = {9, 4, 6, 2, 10, 10};
        Integer[] array2 = {14, 3, 6, 9, 10, 15, 17, 9};                    
        Set hashSet = new HashSet(Arrays.asList(array1)); 
        Set commonElements = new HashSet();        
        for (int i = 0; i < array2.length; i++) {
            if (hashSet.contains(array2[i])) {
                commonElements.add(array2[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Common elements " + commonElements);
    }    
}
```

Output:

Common elements [6, 9, 10]

Answer (score 2):

In APL:

```
∪A1∩A2
```

example:

```
      A1←9, 4, 6, 2, 10, 10
      A1
9 4 6 2 10 10

      A2←14, 3, 6, 9, 10, 15, 17, 9
      A2
14 3 6 9 10 15 17 9

      A1∩A2
9 6 10 10
      ∪A1∩A2
9 6 10
```

Answer (score 2):

Throw your A2 array into a HashSet, then iterate through A1; if the current element is in the set, it's a common element. This takes O(m + n) time and O(min(m, n)) space.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nested loops:

```
commons = empty
for each element a1 in A1
   for each element a2 in A2
      if a1 == a2
         commons.add(a1)
```

Schouldn't matter at all if the arrays have the same size.

Depending on the language and framework used, set operations might come in handy.

Comment: It's actually O(n*m), witch m and n being the sizes of the arrays. Of course, if you know something about the elements faster algorithms might pop up (i.e. if they contain limited range integers or are sorted).

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but it can be done in O(n log n + m log m) and your approach is O(m * n) which is not good.

Comment: Sorry, this is nonsense. It wasn't asked for the fastest implementation at all. And with many real-world small-size applications, this easy tight O(m*n) implementation will be faster than the other approaches. And it's low-maintainance code, too. If there are more constraints to consider, we need to know them. Also, it's not clear if sorting the arrays is allowed at all (or copying is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Try [heapifying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) both arrays followed by a merge to find the intersection.

Java example:

```
public static <E extends Comparable<E>>List<E> intersection(Collection<E> c1,
                                                            Collection<E> c2) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    PriorityQueue<E> q1 = new PriorityQueue<E>(c1),
                     q2 = new PriorityQueue<E>(c2);
    while (! (q1.isEmpty() || q2.isEmpty())) {
        E e1 = q1.peek(), e2 = q2.peek();
        int c = e1.compareTo(e2);
        if (c == 0) result.add(e1);
        if (c <= 0) q1.remove();
        if (c >= 0) q2.remove();
    }
    return result;
}
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245557/algorithm-to-find-if-two-sets-intersect) for more examples of merging.

Comment: nitpicking, but it should be `if(c < 0)` and `if (c > 0)` and also add `else`, otherwise you're evaluating the all 3 conditions EVERY time.

Comment: @st0le, if `c == 0` then all three statements must be executed, otherwise it will go into an infinite loop comparing the same elements over and over again.  You can reduce the number of branches at the cost of duplicating the calls to `remove`.

Answer (score 0):

The Complexity of what I give is `O(N*M + N)`.

Also note that it is *Pseudocode* C And that it provides distinct values.

eg.`[1,1,1,2,2,4]` and `[1,1,1,2,2,2,5]` Will return `[1,2]`

The Complexity is
`N*M` cause of the `for` loops

`+ N` cause of the checking if it already exists in the `ArrayCommon[]` (which is `n` size in case `Array2[]` contains data which duplicate Part of the `Array1[]` Assuming N is the size of the smaller Array (N < M).

```
int Array1[m] = { Whatever };
int Array2[n] = { Whatever };
int ArrayCommon[n] = { };

void AddToCommon(int data)
{
    //How many commons we got so far?
    static int pos = 0; 
    bool found = false;
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= pos ; i++)
    {
        //Already found it?
        if(ArrayCommon[i] == data)
        {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    if(!found)
    {
        //Add it
        ArrayCommon[pos] = data;
        pos++;
    }
}

for(int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0 ; j < n ; j++)
    {
        //Found a Common Element!
        if(Array1[i] == Array2[j])
            AddToCommon(Array1[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you would write `set(A1).intersection(A2)`. This is the optimal O(n + m).

There's ambiguity in your question though. What's the result of A1=[0, 0], A2=[0, 0, 0]? There's reasonable interpretations of your question that give 1, 2, 3, or 6 results in the final array - which does your situation require?

Comment: @Saaed A hashed-based set implementation will give O(n + m) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by using Set intersection. It is very elegant. Even though I did not analyze the time complexity, it is probably in reasonable range.

```
public Set FindCommonElements(Integer[] first, Integer[] second)
{

    Set<Integer> set1=new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(first));
    Set<Integer> set2=new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(second));

    // finds intersecting elements in two sets
    set1.retainAll(set2);

    return set1;

}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
class SortedArr

    def findCommon(a,b)

      j =0
      i =0
      l1=a.length
      l2=b.length

      if(l1 > l2)
            len=l1
      else
            len=l2
      end


     while i < len
          if a[i].to_i > b[j].to_i
              j +=1
          elsif a[i].to_i < b[j].to_i
              i +=1
          else   
              puts a[i] # OR store it in other ds
              i +=1
              j +=1
          end
     end
  end
end

 t = SortedArr.new
 t.findCommon([1,2,3,4,6,9,11,15],[1,2,3,4,5,12,15])
```

Comment: Please do not leave code only answers. They are of no benefit without explanation. Also, you are answering a question that has been solved for over 2 years. What do you feel like you are adding?

Comment: Sorry Nick! This is my first time here. Will keep that in mind. I just wanted to add a Ruby based sol. But anyways will be more careful.